# How to use forwarding to cast rvalue to lvalue reference?

Tags: c++, perfect-forwarding, lvalue-to-rvalue

I'm trying to use an overloaded function to hide passing an int reference to a utility function when I don't care for the returned int data. Why is it that I need to use `T&` instead of `T` as the template argument? And why do I need the intermediate function that defines `i` as an rvalue?

```
class DataClass
{

};

template <typename T>
bool func(T& data, int& i) {
  i = 1;
  cout << "it worked!" << endl;
}

// I would like to remove this function
template <typename T>
bool func(T& data, int&& i) {
  return func(std::forward<T&>(data), std::forward<int&>(i));
}

template <typename T>
bool func(T& data) {
  // Why doesn't this line work?
  // return func(std::forward<T>(data), std::forward<int>(0));
  return func(std::forward<T&>(data), 0);
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  DataClass d;
  func<DataClass>(d);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::forward` is only useful with forwarding references.  `T&` is not such a forwarding reference, so you shouldn't be using `std::forward` here.

Comment: Calling `func(d)` would not be forwarding a reference of `DataClass` to `func(d, 0)`?

Comment: Forwarding references only arise when you declare an rvalue-reference to a deduced template parameter.  i.e. `template <typename T> bool func(T&& data)`.  The "forward" in "forwarding reference" refers to forwarding the _value category_ (lvalue or rvalue) of the expression given, not the value itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Advantages of using forward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582001/advantages-of-using-forward)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `std::forward` at all here.  Except for `int&& i` in the second overload, your parameters all declared as non-const lvalue references, so you can't pass an rvalue to any of them.  And in the `int&&` overload, if you want to call the lvalue function from the rvalue function, you can just name the parameter `i`, because a name is always an lvalue.

```
template <typename T>
bool func(T& data, int& i) {
  i = 1;
  cout << "it worked!" << endl;
}

template <typename T>
bool func(T& data, int&& i) {
  return func(data, i);
}

template <typename T>
bool func(T& data) {
  return func(data, 0);
}
```

If you'd like to remove a function, note that it's actually the `int&` that does something effectively different: it changes `i` to 1. The rvalue overload technically also does, but something that has been passed as an rvalue should generally be ignored after that point, so callers should only count on `func(T&, int&&)` to print the message to `cout`.  And to take an `int` that isn't an lvalue... just take an `int`.

```
template <typename T>
bool func(T& data, int& i) {
  i = 1;
  cout << "it worked!" << endl;
}

template <typename T>
bool func(T& data, int i=0) {
  return func(data, i); // effect on i is ignored.
}

// Okay to pass a const int?
template <typename T>
bool func(T&, const volatile int&&) = delete;
```

That third deleted template preserves one behavior of your original code, though it's not clear if you actually want that behavior or not.  In the function

```
void test() {
    DataClass d;
    const int n = 5;
    func(d, n);
}
```

... the original code would have failed to compile, since a `const int` lvalue can't bind to either `int&` or `int&&`.  But the change to a parameter of simply `int` would allow this `test` to compile, by making a copy of `n` to be the plain `int` parameter.  Then the change to that `int i` just gets discarded, even though you gave `n` to the function.  The deleted template is a better match for the `const int` lvalue `n`, so it would cause `test` to fail to compile.  If you do want the behavior where `func(d, n)` is valid but has no effect on `n`, just take out that deleted template.